# Spritekit animation doesn't work in iOS7 but does in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I made a game to teach kids how to count. When you tap the right number it explodes and the next one starts to have a glowing animation as a tip.

A while ago I noticed that this specific animation doesn't work in iOS7.

This is how it looks like:
[image: animation]

I made this with a NSTimer, that and a method with the animation:

```
-(void)addGlow
{
    if (!timer) {
        [self startTimer];
    }
    SKSpriteNode* back = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:self.body.texture];
    back.blendMode = SKBlendModeAdd;
    back.position = CGPointMake(0, 0 - 2);
    [back runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:0.72 duration:0] completion:nil];
    SKAction* group = [SKAction group:@[[SKAction scaleTo:1 duration:0.8],[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:0.8]]];
    [self addChild:back];
    [back runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[group,[SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
}
```

And this is my start method:

```
-(void)startTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(addGlow) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I did debug it, and the method is called with no errors on both iOS versions. Any ideas of how can I discovery what is going on?

Comment: Just a side note...When using NSTimer be aware that it doesn't respect node's paused state. That means if you pause your game (pause whole view, or scene) the timer will not stop. About the animation problem...Can you be more specific what is the expected behaviour? What is not working ?

Comment: @Whirlwind I didn't know that, thanks. About the animation.. I create a secondary note, with the balloon texture, and scale down it's size. Then I animate it to grow and fade away. So, the right balloon to be tapped keeps glowing and the kid that is playing have a tip to what he/she needs to do. And it works fine on iOS8. But in iOS7 this animation simply doesn't happen in graphical terms. You can't see anything different, but the methods are called correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're not setting zPosition. Make sure it contains what you expect. Apple made changes to the responder chain between iOS 7 and 8 so I wouldn't be surprised if they had changed how zPositions are initialised.